# How to extend custom (non-core) blocks?

Tags: hooks, block-editor

I created few custom blocks which work just fine.

I plan for these blocks to have common attributes and I'm using the `blocks.registerBlockType` filter to add an attribute, here is my code:

```
import { blocksWithSharedAttributes } from '../blocks-wth-shared-attributes.jsx'; // an array of names of custom blocks.
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;

const addToggleRenderBlockAttribute = ( settings, name ) => {

    if ( ! blocksWithSharedAttributes.includes( name ) ) {
        return settings; // This callback returns here. :(
    }

    settings.attributes = Object.assign( settings.attributes, {
        toggleBlockRender: {
            type: 'boolean',
            default: false,
        },
    } );

    return settings;
};

addFilter( 'blocks.registerBlockType', 'someNamespace/attribute/toggleBlockRender', addToggleRenderBlockAttribute );
```

The problem I'm facing is that the `name` argument doesn't have any of the custom blocks I created and due to that the callback returns at line 7.

The `name` argument only has `core/` blocks. How can I make custom blocks appear in the filter?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

`addFilter( 'blocks.registerBlockType )` needs to be called before the call to `registerBlockType`.

Comment: Can you explain how did you extend your custom block in detail ?